# posts in multiple languages?

Tags: wordpress, post, localization, translation, article

im searching for a Tool/ way to write 2 different Articles in 1 Article page. For example: I want to write English articles and an translation in German with a few differences and when someone want to see the Articles of the whole page in German they just need to press a Button to change to the translation of all articles. I hope this is understandable and im looking forward to an answer. Btw the Multisite feature don´t work due to another tool. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some plugins for multilingual websites (Wpml, QTranslate, Polylang etc.) but I'd suggest the solution I'm using myself.
I'm using the [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin. You can easily install it either by downloading it manually or (which I prefer) by simply searching for it from your *Plugins* page.
Then, you have different options to separate your languages, namely:

- Each language on its own virtual subdomain (my favorite way, btw) — `en.yoursite.com`, `de.yoursite.com` etc. To do this, you need to add an `*.yoursite.com` wildcarded domain in your control panel (it's quite easy in CPanel, for instance).
- Each language in its own virtual folder — `yoursite.com/en/`, `yoursite.com/de/` etc.
- Languages switch with a parameter in the URL — `yoursite.com?lang=en`, `yoursite.com?lang=de` etc.

Whatever you choose, you'll be able to:

- Select the languages you need, customize their order and how they are shown;
- Select the default language to show when a user opens `yoursite.com`;
- Choose where to put your language switcher;
- when writing/editing a post, indicate its language and have a link to add translation in any of the language you had selected for your website. Note that this is very nifty since, if a user gets a direct link to one of your posts in English and then switches the language to German with your widget, he/she gets directly to the translated post;
- have quite separate interfaces in all of the languages, so, for example, Greek or Japanese users won't see inscriptions in English and vice versa;
- Translate categories, tags, titles, taglines, dates and so on.

Comment: Thank you. After I have tested the Plugin I think that fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

this should solve all your issues :

**Set Up a Multilingual Blog:**

Do you want to create a multilingual blog? Here are three different ways you can set up your blog if you have content in multiple languages:

**Option 1: One Blog, One Post**

You can create one blog, and have each post or page contain the same content in both languages.

Multilingual blog - one blog one post

Write your posts: When you write a post, do the first half in one language. Then, at the bottom of the post, write it in the other language. That way, anyone reading your site just knows they need to scroll.

Link to the other language: In the beginning of each post, you can add a page jump so that your readers can skip ahead to their language.

**Option 2: One Blog, Two Posts**

You can create one blog, and have different posts and pages with the same content in each language.

Blog with separate posts/pages and custom menus in English and Spanish.
One blog with separate posts/pages and custom menus in English and Spanish.
Write your posts: When you write a post, write it in one language. Then, create a new post and write it in the second language. You can add language categories to your posts to organize them.

Link to the other language: You can also have a link on each post or page to send people to the same content in the other language.

Create a language-specific menu: You can use custom menus to make it easier for your readers to find all the posts in each language:

Create a new custom menu for each language.
Add the pages for each language into the custom menu.
Add a category page for the blog posts in that language.
Add a custom menu widget to your sidebar, and adjust the widget visibility so it only appears on posts and pages in that language. Here is an example of the widget visibility settings for an English custom menu:
Multilingual blog - Custom menu settings

**Option 3: Two Blogs**

You can create two separate blogs, one for each language.

English site with links to separate sites in French and Spanish.
English site with links to separate sites in French and Spanish.
Create both blogs: Create two sites using the same theme. If you need to create another site for your alternate-language content, refer to this support article for adding a blog to your account.

Choose a domain for each blog: Do you want your blog to have a custom domain? You can use two different domain names or set up a subdomain of the main domain. For example, you can have one blog at my-english-site.com and the other at mi-sitio-español.com, or you could have my-website.com and es.my-website.com. It’s up to you!

Link to the other language: You can use custom menus to cross-link your blogs. Add a custom link to each menu that links to your other blog, so visitors can switch to that language easily.

Write your posts: Set one blog’s language to the first language in which you write, the other to the second language. Each time you write a post, write it twice, once in Language #1 on blog #1 and again in Language #2 on blog #2.

Your followers can subscribe to one blog or both, and your posts will appear in the Tags section in the Reader for each blog’s language.

**UPDATE :**

This will solve your problem.... I thought you do not want to translate sidebar and all...

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/

Comment: Thank you the second and third one seems like the things i was searching for. I will try it.

Comment: Sorry but after trying the Features I sadly must say that it wasn´t the perfect solution for my Problem because it wont translate all (Like Sidebar)- The 3 Solution maybe would do it but thats sadly not what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution for you.

i thought you do not need to edit the language of sidebar.

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/

this plugin will allow you to add custom text for each post.. this is more userfriendly as it allows you to create the 2 posts in 2 languages from the same page.